# How to load an assembly outside my web app's bin directory

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to load my assemblies from a location other than the bin folder.

How can I accomplish this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

note:

My previous answer was incorrect. Sam Holder's supposition sounded plausible so I wrote some tests to confirm.

Consider it confirmed.

To test, add a reference to a project or dll and set 'Copy Local' to false. Make sure you 'show all files' and delete the bin dir or you are going to have a lingering dll in there.

**Global.asax**

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {

        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
            currentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(currentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
        }

        System.Reflection.Assembly currentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.Name == "ClassLibrary1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")
            {
                String assemblyPath = @"C:\Projects\StackOverflowAnswers\WebApplication1\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.dll";
                Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);
                return assembly;
            }
            return null;

        }
.....
```

The OP should perhaps give me an upvote but Sam should get the check.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if you can do this in asp.net, but in .net applications you can provide a delegate to the AssemblyResolve event in the current AppDomain

```
AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
currentDomain.AssemblyResolve += assemblyResolver.ResolveEventHandler;
```

when the application has any assembly references that it can't resolve it will call this delegate to get the assembly resolved. You can then simply return the assembly requested from the delegate:

```
String assemblyPath = //some logic to determine the location of the assembly
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom (assemblyPath);
return assembly;
```

Comment: +1 this is a possibility that I did not think of. I will try it.

Comment: Confirmed. Good catch. I got my learning in today, now can nop. ;-)

Comment: Sky, thanks for taking the time and effort to confirm this.  This is the sort of thing that makes SO different from other sites.

Answer (score 0):

Add the folder you do want to use to your PATH environment variable. This will let you type my-program.exe from the command line and it will run.

If you are trying to load something internally as part of your program, you can change the working directory `SetCurrentDirectory` or just use the full path for each file access.

Comment: I don't know that this will work for an ASP.NET application (the kind that has a `bin` folder and not `bin\Debug`).

Comment: i will sharp my question.
im building web application.
i want that the dll on the server will load from diffrent directory then the bin folder.

Comment: Ok, with the more info, it sounds like Sky has the right idea. In the future, give more background on your question and it will help you get better answers.